# Microsoft Graph console application - OAuth

Tags: oauth, microsoft-graph-api, token, sharepoint-online, onedrive

Is possible for an console application to open a browser, have the user login to Microsoft, grant permissions, and return the OAuth token to the application automatically?

I would like to minimize the need to create a Django or Flask application if the only thing it will do is open a window for the user to login.

I am trying to automate uploads to Microsoft OneDrive that requires minimal user input, zero input would be good but I do not think that is possible.

Python is the preferred language, but I am open to all languages out there.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to prompt a browser panel from console app. Please take a reference of below samples:

- [Microsoft Graph C# Console Connect Sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/console-csharp-connect-sample/tree/a443ced44f5e3cb27ea5dbb10f20b4d1d0c87702)
- [Python console application for Microsoft Graph](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python-sample-console-app#python-console-application-for-microsoft-graph)

I have a test it on my tenant, it wroks fine here:

[image]

BR